# I have a specific property key within a dataset in neo4j. How do i find all the distinct labels for a specific property key?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know the code below gives me a list of my main nodes in my dataset and their properties;

```
MATCH(n)
WITH LABELS(n) AS Main_Nodes, KEYS(n) AS keys
UNWIND labels AS label
UNWIND keys AS key
RETURN DISTINCT label, COLLECT(DISTINCT key) AS Properties
ORDER BY label
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that these are rather expensive graph-wide queries, but to find distinct labels of nodes with a specific property key you can use the following:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE exists(n.myKey)
UNWIND labels(n) as label
RETURN collect(DISTINCT label) as labels
```

EDIT

As far as finding all distinct values of a key in the database, that's also going to be a expensive graph-wide query, but you can do this with a query like this:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE exists(n.myKey)
RETURN DISTINCT n.myKey as values
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However I am not sure I phrased my question right. I have a property key and this key has different labels...e.g. lets say the key is "name", so under this key I have different "name" labels like James, John, Linda, Emma etc...I want to find out how I can list all the different "name "labels under the property key "name". Does that make sense?

Comment: I think we need to be very specific on the terms and definitions in use here. A property has a key and a value. For the property `name:'Clark Kent'`, "name" is the key, and "Clark Kent" is the value. Labels have nothing to do with properties and apply only to nodes (nodes can be multilabeled). I wouldn't expect to see name labels like :Linda on nodes, but I would expect to see property values like `name:'Linda'`. Can you describe your use case using these terms?

Comment: Apologies. Yes I have a key "name" and I would like to list out all the distinct values within that key. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, should be an easier query overall, though still expensive on a large graph when you aren't constraining the query with labels or other filtering. Added this to my answer.